# Infinite scrolling with Firestore

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've done loads of searching around trying to find a helpful post or article on this subject and so far with no luck. There are plenty of pagination/infinite scroll tutorials but these are Angular tutorials I would prefer to keep it pure and simple JS.

What I want to do is lazy load data in from Firestore as the user scrolls down a div. So initially loading a small set of the data in and then bring in more as the user scrolls. So far I have the following code:

```js
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDEkmqcwWFz6xCYAuS1jXCBcpxzCv_IlBE",
    authDomain: "test-903a0.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-903a0.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-903a0",
    storageBucket: "test-903a0.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "117341455405"
});
  
// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
const db = firebase.firestore();

var first = db.collection("users").orderBy("first").limit(2);
first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
    var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
    documentSnapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
        $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + doc.data().first + '</td><td>' + doc.data().last + '</td><td>' + doc.data().born + '</td></tr>');
    })
    var next = db.collection("users").orderBy("first").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(2);
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.scroll').on('scroll', function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                next.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
                    documentSnapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
                        $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + doc.data().first + '</td><td>' + doc.data().last + '</td><td>' + doc.data().born + '</td></tr>');
                    });
                });
            };
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.scroll {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.table-container {
    height: 1000px;
}
#myTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
#myTable, th, td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.2.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="scroll">
  <div class="table-container">
    <table id="myTable">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I scroll this div it loads the next 2 results in from the firestore database. However, when scrolling thereafter, it simply loads the previous 2 results back into the table. Can someone please advise me where I'm going wrong here as I'm at a loss?

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. The firebase-database tag is used for firebase real-time database while this question is about firestore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to update `lastVisible` and `next` every time you fetch a new page...  So something like (untested):

```
    $('.scroll').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            var next = db.collection("users").orderBy("first").startAfter(lastVisible).limit(2);
            next.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
               lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
                documentSnapshots.forEach(function(doc) {
                    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + doc.data().first + '</td><td>' + doc.data().last + '</td><td>' + doc.data().born + '</td></tr>');
                });
            });
        };
    });
```